# The certificate request was submitted to the online authority, but was not issued. The request was denied

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority, ssl-certificate-renewal

I've a Hyper-V lab with few VMs. I'm trying to renew expired server certificate for one of my virtual machines which is running Windows Server 2019 (version 1809). I'm trying to renew the certificate from IIS:

[image]

Certificate authority is residing on domain controller which is running Windows Server 2016 (version 1607). When I go through the certificate renewal wizard via IIS manager it gives below error:

> The certificate request was submitted to the online authority, but was
> not issued. The request was denied.

[image]

What all I've tried so far:

- Rebooted domain controller
- Then rebooted the problematic machine
- Then ran `gpupdate` command on the problematic machine

Answer (score 1):

You cannot renew expired certificates, which is most likely the reason why the request was denied. You need to check the CA logs if you want to see the reason.